# TableEdit Plugin - Two tables on same page - TableEdit Plugin works ONLY when both Tables have Data

Tags: php, jquery, tabledit

I have a single php webpage where i have two result tables. I have applied TablEdit Plugins to add live Edit / Delete features.
It works perfectly ONLY when both the Tables have results, if any of them is empty, the TablEdit Plugin (Save/Delete do not appear) doesnt work.

I have separated the $(document).ready(function(){ } for each table and placing them in two different  blocks. BUT same problem.

```
<!-- UNPAID TABLE -->
$id = $_GET ['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dues INNER JOIN institutions ON institutions.id = 
dues.idfk and dues.idfk ='$id' and dues.dstatus ='Unpaid'";


$data = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows ($data);

if($total != 0)
{
?>

<table id="unpaid_table" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr style='text-align: center;'>
<th style='display: none;'>DID</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Penalty</th>
<th>Total Dues</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
{

echo "
      <tr style='text-align: center;'>                      
  <td style='display: none;'>".$result ['did']."</td>                                        
      <td>".$result ['year']."</td>                                      
      <td>".$result['amount']."</td>                                         
      <td>".$result['penalty']."</td>                                        
      <td>".$result['total']."</td>                                      
      <td>".$result['dstatus']."</td>                                    
      </tr>";                                       
  }
 }
else
{
  echo "<div style='color:red;'>No Records</div>";
}
?>
</tbody>            
</table>


<!-- PAID TABLE -->
$id = $_GET ['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dues INNER JOIN institutions ON institutions.id = 
dues.idfk and dues.idfk ='$id' and dues.dstatus ='Paid'";


$data = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows ($data);

if($total != 0)
{
?>

<table id="paid_table" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr style='text-align: center;'>
<th style='display: none;'>DID</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Penalty</th>
<th>Total Dues</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
{

echo "
      <tr style='text-align: center;'>                      
  <td style='display: none;'>".$result ['did']."</td>                                        
      <td>".$result ['year']."</td>                                      
      <td>".$result['amount']."</td>                                         
      <td>".$result['penalty']."</td>                                        
      <td>".$result['total']."</td>                                      
      <td>".$result['dstatus']."</td>                                    
      </tr>";                                       
  }
 }
else
{
  echo "<div style='color:red;'>No Records</div>";
}
?>
</tbody>            
</table>


<!-- TablEdit Script -->

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#paid_table').Tabledit({
      url:'duesaction.php',
      columns:{
      identifier:[0, "did"],
      editable:[
     [1, 'year'], 
     [2, 'amount'], 
     [3, 'penalty'], 
     [4, 'total'], 
     [5, 'status', '{"Paid": "Paid", "Unpaid": "Unpaid"}']
     ]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'delete')
       {
        $('#'+data.did).remove();
       }
      }
     });
});
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#unpaid_table').Tabledit({
      url:'duesaction.php',
      columns:{
      identifier:[0, "did"],
      editable:[
      [1, 'year'], 
      [2, 'amount'], 
      [3, 'penalty'], 
      [4, 'total'], 
      [5, 'status', '{"Paid": "Paid", "Unpaid": "Unpaid"}']
      ]
     },
     restoreButton:false,
     onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
     {
      if(data.action == 'delete')
      {
       $('#'+data.did).remove();
      }
     }
    });

});

</script>
```

Works perfectly fine when both the Tables has data, but doesnt work if any of tables has no data.
I want it working in both the scenarios.

Please HELP.

Comment: Are you not getting an error, either browser console or server/php? Would help narrow things down.

Comment: @ficuscr No error in console bro.  i think something is missing out, when any of the Tables is empty

Comment: Agreed, and almost certainly something generating an error. Some init error? Only suggestion I can make is check the conditionals. I see `if($total != 0)
`, are you simply skipping over when no result?

Comment: Yes i am simply skipping over when no result. basic select statement with condition and pulling result if ANY.